# SAS Array Declaration

Tags: sas, wrds-compusat, wrds

I was reading the [SAS code for calculating NBBO](https://wrds-web.wharton.upenn.edu/wrds/support/Data/_005Using%20TAQ%20Data%20Efficiently/_028NBBO.cfm), and I came across the following code:

```
array nexb nexb:; array nexo nexo:; array sexb sexb:; array sexo sexo:;
```

I was wondering what does the statement `array nexb nexb:;` do here?

Comment: Here's a link to the other various ways of listing variables using shortcuts: http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrcon/69852/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p0wphcpsfgx6o7n1sjtqzizp1n39.htm

Comment: Just noticed the Wharton copyright on the code above, please make sure it's ok to post this macro publicly.

Comment: @Reeza I think it is fine? Because it is part of a Wharton tutorial teaching people how to use their services. Also I sourced the material and it's authors. In any case if Wharton sends me an email asking me to take it down I will follow their instructions.

Comment: That's not how it works. If you're unsure inquire, since the tutorials appear behind a secure log in I suspect they're not freely available.

Comment: Ok I deleted the code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two things:

`nexb:` is a variable list with a wildcard.  It expands to the list of all variables on the PDV *at that point in the data step* that begin with `nexb`.  So the same as `nexb1-nexb17` more than likely (without knowing what's in the datasets in the `set` statement though).  It's identical, and just used to make it easier to change that `17` sometime later without having to do so twice.

`array nexb nexb:` creates an array, which is simply an organized variable list that allows you to say `nexb[1]` instead of `nexb1`, which is really more useful since `[1]` can be `[i]` or some other variable, while `nexb1` cannot.  So it allows you to go through a list of variables one at a time and use them or change them.  The array does not exist in the dataset itself and is not persistent, it's just a shorthand way to refer to the variables.

Comment: Does "array nexb nexb:" declares two arrays?

Comment: No.  `array nexb nexb:` is declaring array `nexb` comprising of variables `nexb:`.

Comment: And `array nexb;` would not work.  You need to supply it either a list of variables or a count.

Comment: Hi Joe, I am reading the source code again: https://wrds-web.wharton.upenn.edu/wrds/research/applications/sas_files/nbbo.sas I found it pretty weird. Why does the author defines variable nexb1-17 and then add it to an array? Can't he just directly create an array?